# unable to build and install openH264 video codec for ios

Tags: ios, makefile, pjsip, openh264

I'm trying to install [openH264 for ios](https://github.com/cisco/openh264#for-ios-builds). Here are the steps I run from the openH264's current directory using terminal:

```
$ make OS=ios ARCH=armv7
```

The default location of openh264 installation was set `/usr/local` in the *makefile*. So, I just ran the following command

```
$make install
```

But I got this error:

```
nasm -DUNIX64 -DPREFIX -f macho64 -Icodec/common/x86/   -o codec/encoder/core/x86/coeff.o codec/encoder/core/x86/coeff.asm
nasm: fatal: unrecognised output format `macho64' - use -hf for a list
type `nasm -h' for help
make: *** [codec/encoder/core/x86/coeff.o] Error 1
```

I am following [this](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/ticket/1758) instructions also to build the codec. Besides after successful installation I have to include it into [pjsip for video support](https://trac.pjsip.org/repos/wiki/Getting-Started/iPhone#VideoSupport).
I don't know what is the problem with the command? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With help of [this](https://github.com/cisco/openh264/issues/1421) I solved it.

Just run :

```
$sudo make OS=ios ARCH=arm64 install
```

for arm64 architecture. Change the ARCH value to armv7, armv7s for devices and i386 and x86_64 for the simulator. By default it installed in `/usr/local/lib` directory. I used sudo to get admin privilege as at the end of complication it throwing error that permission denied to `mkdir -p /usr/local/lib` .

Comment: I am totally new  to MAC OS. Yes, it's much easier to make OpenH264 with this command.  But I faced another problem while integrating OpenH264 library files in Xcode. But after a long observation and study I managed to integrate these library files in my Xcode IOS Application.

Comment: @RajibTheKing: Please vote up if this code helped you.